# bootstrap add new tab while other section remains common for all tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have to add a new tab section on click of "New Tab" for half on my page. The remaining half is not included however I have to make sure that its value changes depending on which tab I have selected on top. Is this possible?

Any suggestion on how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: share what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have only tried to add a new tab. I am thinking since the half page is not in the new tab, its DOM objects' name and ids will remain same and  wont be able to save different values upon selecting different tab. I googled to find a solution but did not find any so was wondering if it was even possible.